# ALT+arrow keys to navigate between cells in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Run the snippet below and focus the first input of the table.
Use the ALT key+any arrow key on your keyboard to navigate between the cells.
Moving forward or down works great, but when you reach the third row it will take you up to the first cell instead of the second cell if your focus is on a div (compare to an input where it actually works).
The next problem is that if you press ALT+left arrow it will take you back to the first cell, when you should move to the previous cell.

Does it have anything to do with the `$new_field[0]` ?

```js
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
  el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
      && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

$(document).on('keydown', '.field', function(e) {
  // If arrow up / down
  if( (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40 || e.which == 37 || e.which == 39) && e.altKey )
  {
    var $self = $(this);
    var $field = $self.closest('td.nav-field:visible');
    var data_field = $field.attr('data-field');
    var $row = $self.closest('tr');
    if( e.which == 38 )
    {
      var $target = $row.prevAll('tr:visible');
      $new_field = $target.find('td.nav-field[data-field="' + data_field + '"]:visible .field');
    }
    else if( e.which == 40 )
    {
      var $target = $row.nextAll('tr:visible').eq(0);
      $new_field = $target.find('td.nav-field[data-field="' + data_field + '"]:visible .field');
    }
    else if( e.which == 37 )
    {
      var $target = $field.prevAll('td.nav-field:visible');
      $new_field = $target.find('.field');
    }
    else if( e.which == 39 )
    {
      var $target = $field.nextAll('td.nav-field:visible').eq(0);
      $new_field = $target.find('.field');
    }
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      if( $new_field.is('input') )
      {
        $new_field.select();
      }
      else if( $new_field.is('div[contenteditable]') )
      {
        placeCaretAtEnd($new_field[0]);
      }
      else
      {
        $new_field.focus();
      }
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-field="1" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 1" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="2" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 1</div></td>
    <td data-field="3" class="nav-field" style="display: none;"><input value="Input 2" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="4" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 2</div></td>
    <td data-field="5" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 3" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="6">Not Editable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td data-field="1" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 1" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="2" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 1</div></td>
    <td data-field="3" class="nav-field" style="display: none;"><input value="Input 2" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="4" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 2</div></td>
    <td data-field="5" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 3" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="6">Not Editable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-field="1" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 1" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="2" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 1</div></td>
    <td data-field="3" class="nav-field" style="display: none;" class="field"><input value="Input 2"></td>
    <td data-field="4" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 2</div></td>
    <td data-field="5" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 3" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="6">Not Editable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-field="1" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 1" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="2" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 1</div></td>
    <td data-field="3" class="nav-field" style="display: none;" class="field"><input value="Input 2"></td>
    <td data-field="4" class="nav-field"><div contenteditable="true" class="field">Content Editable 2</div></td>
    <td data-field="5" class="nav-field"><input value="Input 3" class="field"></td>
    <td data-field="6">Not Editable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the "option" key?

Comment: @ScottMarcus The alt key on your keyboard

Comment: That's the ALT key, not the "option" key. AFAIK there is no such thing as an "option" key.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm too macified :) https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMWZE9WgeX_EQoxzynS8uJLdbuoRoegTcVDqe3HJYbDON-BLWSfw

Comment: @Scott, yes, there is an option key... on Macs. It's the same as far as JavaScript is concerned as the Alt key.

Comment: Oh. I'm not a Mac user. You should be clear when posting.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah, sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: it seems to me to be done very complicated and difficult to correct. Why do not you just use `table.rows[x].cells[y]` methods?

Comment: @MisterJojo I didn't know about that method. How do you do it? Note that it has to skip hidden cells and rows. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Alt+arrow right, in FF, takes me forward one page in my history -- can't test in the snippet. (no need to reply.)

Comment: @wazz hm, not in my FF. What OS/version are you on? Not sure ctrl or cmd/meta key would be any better though and shift is used for selecting text.

Comment: I'm talking about the snippet on/in this very page.

Comment: @wazz yeah I get it, but I'm also in FF in it does not take me to a different page. So what OS/FF version are you in?

Comment: `.eq(0)` on `.prevAll()` as well solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why I should make you a complete solution, so here is just an example of using native Javascript methods to handle your problem...

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-Table tbody')
    , nbRows  = myTable.rows.length
    , nbCells = myTable.rows[0].cells.length
    , moving  = { ArrowUp    : p=>{ p.r = (--p.r +nbRows ) % nbRows  }
                , ArrowLeft  : p=>{ p.c = (--p.c +nbCells) % nbCells }
                , ArrowDown  : p=>{ p.r = ++p.r % nbRows  }
                , ArrowRight : p=>{ p.c = ++p.c % nbCells }
                }

document.onkeydown=e=>
  {
  let currentPos = myTable.querySelector('.select')
    , evt        = (e==null ? event:e)
    , pos        = { r:currentPos.parentNode.rowIndex
                   , c:currentPos.cellIndex
                   }

  if ( evt.altKey && moving[evt.code] )
    {
    moving[evt.code](pos)
    currentPos.classList.remove('select')
    myTable.rows[pos.r].cells[pos.c].classList.add('select')
    }
  }
```

```css
#my-Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#my-Table td {
  width:20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.select { background-color: aqua }
```

```html
<p>ALt arrow key usage...</p>

<table id="my-Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td class='select'>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>e</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>h</td></tr>
    <tr><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td><td>l</td></tr>
    <tr><td>m</td><td>n</td><td>o</td><td>p</td></tr>
    <tr><td>q</td><td>r</td><td>s</td><td>t</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's not that I wanted to do it, but when a problem has entered my mind, I want to finish it.

move key is [alt] + [shift] + [arrow keys] because [alt] + [arrow keys] corresponding for window moves on my computer (LINUX)

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-Table tbody')
    , nbRows  = myTable.rows.length
    , nbCells = myTable.rows[0].cells.length
    , movKey  = { ArrowUp    : p=>{ p.r = (--p.r +nbRows ) % nbRows  }
                , ArrowLeft  : p=>{ p.c = (--p.c +nbCells) % nbCells }
                , ArrowDown  : p=>{ p.r = ++p.r % nbRows  }
                , ArrowRight : p=>{ p.c = ++p.c % nbCells }
                }

// get On Focus event on Table elements
myTable
  .querySelectorAll('input, [contenteditable=true]')
  .forEach(elm=>{elm.onfocus=e=>
    {
    let sPos  = myTable.querySelector('.select')
      , tdPos = elm.parentNode

    if (sPos) sPos.classList.remove('select')

    tdPos.classList.add('select')
    }
  })


document.onkeydown=e=>
  {
  let sPos = myTable.querySelector('.select')
    , evt  = (e==null ? event:e)
    , pos  = { r: sPos?sPos.parentNode.rowIndex:-1
             , c: sPos?sPos.cellIndex:-1
             }

  if ( sPos                 // previous pos focus exist...
    && evt.altKey
    && evt.shiftKey         // addin shift to control
    && movKey[evt.code] )   // evt.ctrlKey... ?
    {
    let loop    = true
      , nxFocus = null
      , cell    = null
    do
      {
      movKey[evt.code](pos)
      cell    = myTable.rows[pos.r].cells[pos.c]                    // possible <td> for new focus...
      nxFocus = cell.querySelector('input, [contenteditable=true]') // get focussable element of <td>

      if ( nxFocus 
      && cell.style.display!=='none' 
      && cell.parentNode.style.display!=='none')
        {
        nxFocus.focus()
        loop = false
        }
      }
      while (loop)
    }
  }
```

```css
#my-Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#my-Table td {
  min-width:20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.select { background-color: aqua } /* just for the control, delete this line when commissioning the operation */
```

```html
<table id="my-Table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input placeholder="r0, c0"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 1 r0, c1</div></td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input placeholder="r0, c2"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 2 r0, c3</div></td>
      <td><input placeholder="r0, c4"></td>
      <td>Not Editable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
      <td><input placeholder="r1, c1"></td><td><div contenteditable=" true">Content Editable 1</div></td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input value="Input 2"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 2</div></td>
      <td><input value="Input 3"></td>
      <td>Not Editable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input  placeholder="r2, c0"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 1</div></td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input value="Input 2"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 2</div></td>
      <td><input value="Input 3"></td>
      <td>Not Editable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="Input 1"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 1</div></td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input value="Input 2"></td>
      <td><div contenteditable="true">Content Editable 2</div></td>
      <td><input value="Input 3"></td>
      <td>Not Editable</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I wasn't expecting a full example, but like I mentioned, how would you skip hidden columns and rows if you go by indexes?

Comment: @SeaBass  starting on `currentPos` you can get `currentPos.querySelector('input')` and check anything, dispaly value, contenteditable value...