# Press arrow key move focus within table, including merging fields, just like in Excel

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, I tried to make tables, and I can already transfer focus within a single table, but when the table has merge fields, the focus movement becomes abnormal.

difference between expected and actual active.
[image: difference]

My code  is [Code_jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fallfall1995/jmL8unfp/10/) and [Code_codepen](https://codepen.io/fallfall1995/pen/eYxOqda) , this two code are same. And I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939343/6676790)  to modify it to the code what I need.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let myTable = document.querySelectorAll("table");
  let get_focus_elm = "input[type='text'], select";
  if (myTable.length > 0) {
    let nbRows = {};
    let nbCells = {};
    let movKey = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
      nbRows[index] = myTable[index].rows.length;
      for (let index_2 = 0, temp = 0; index_2 < nbRows[index]; index_2++) {
        if (myTable[index].rows[index_2].cells.length > temp) {
          temp = myTable[index].rows[index_2].cells.length;
          nbCells[index] = myTable[index].rows[index_2].cells.length;
        }
      }
      movKey[index] = {
        ArrowUp: (p) => {
          p.r = (--p.r + nbRows[index]) % nbRows[index];
        },
        ArrowLeft: (p) => {
          p.c = (--p.c + nbCells[index]) % nbCells[index];
        },
        ArrowDown: (p) => {
          p.r = ++p.r % nbRows[index];
        },
        ArrowRight: (p) => {
          p.c = ++p.c % nbCells[index];
        }
      };
    }
    // console.log(nbRows);
    // console.log(nbCells);

    // get On Focus event on Table elements
    myTable.forEach((tbl) => {
      tbl.querySelectorAll(get_focus_elm).forEach((elm) => {
        elm.onfocus = (e) => {
          let sPos = null;
          for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
            if (myTable[index].querySelector(".select") != null) {
              sPos = myTable[index].querySelector(".select");
            }
          }
          let tdPos = elm.parentNode;

          if (sPos) {
            sPos.classList.remove("select");
          }

          tdPos.classList.add("select");
        };
      });
    });

    document.onkeydown = (e) => {
      let sPos = null;
      let sPos_index = null;
      for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
        if (myTable[index].querySelector(".select") != null) {
          sPos = myTable[index].querySelector(".select");
          sPos_index = index;
        }
      }
      let evt = e == null ? event : e;
      let pos = {};
      for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
        pos[index] = {
          r: sPos ? sPos.parentNode.rowIndex : -1,
          c: sPos ? sPos.cellIndex : -1
        };
      }

      if (sPos && movKey[sPos_index][evt.code]) {
        let loop = true;
        let nxFocus = {};
        for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
          nxFocus[index] = null;
        }
        let cell = {};
        for (let index = 0; index < myTable.length; index++) {
          cell[index] = null;
        }
        while (loop) {
          movKey[sPos_index][evt.code](pos[sPos_index]);
          cell[sPos_index] =
            myTable[sPos_index].rows[pos[sPos_index].r].cells[
              pos[sPos_index].c
            ]; // possible <td> for new focus...
          console.clear();
          while (cell[sPos_index] == null) {
            movKey[sPos_index]["ArrowLeft"](pos[sPos_index]);
            cell[sPos_index] =
              myTable[sPos_index].rows[pos[sPos_index].r].cells[
                pos[sPos_index].c
              ]; // possible <td> for new focus...
          }
          let sel_elm = cell[sPos_index].querySelector(get_focus_elm);

          nxFocus[sPos_index] = sel_elm; // get focussable element of <td>
          if (nxFocus[sPos_index]) {
            nxFocus[sPos_index].focus();
            console.log(
              `${sPos_index} : ${pos[sPos_index].r} : ${pos[sPos_index].c}`
            );
            loop = false;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Consolas", "微軟正黑體";
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* width: 100px; */
}

table tr,
table td {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>test1</caption>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td colspan=2><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <caption>test2</caption>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td rowspan=2><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <caption>test3</caption>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I used `rows.lenth` and `cols.lenth` to count my cells, but if `<td>` have colspan ≧ 2, those counts will not shift focus correctly as I'd like.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform like jsfiddle.

Comment: @CBroe  sorry, unable to join snippet when uploading questions for first time. I've edited it again.